# Post Data with jquery/ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to retrieve data from my form when I post(submit) the data. But I have some ignorance about ajax with jquery.

Today, my code looks like this:

```
$(function() {
    $(".apply_up").submit(function(e){    
        $.post("controller/ajax.php", function(data) {
            alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
        }); 
    });
});
```

And here's my HTML:

```
<form name="Apply" class="apply_up" method="Post">
    <input type="image" src="img/t_up.png" id="ajax" name="t_up" value="1 ">
</form>
```

I want to pick up value = "1"

Comment: Just use the normal jquery selectors like `$("#ajax").attr("value")`

Comment: For `value` it's better to use `val()`. Also, for code longevity, it's better to use `prop()`.

Comment: answered with code plz :)

Comment: @MaxTorstensson Did you miss it? I already did...

Comment: can anyone advise on how I should send value to a php function then?

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the value and then pass it through:

```
$(".apply_up").submit(function(e){    
    var the_val = $('#ajax').val();
    $.post("controller/ajax.php", { 'value': the_val }, function(data) {
        alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this one:

```
 $(".apply_up").submit(function(e){  
    e.preventDefault();
    var imgVal = $('#ajax').val();  
    $.post("controller/ajax.php", {value : imgVal}, function(data) {
        alert("Data Loaded: " + data.value);
    }, "json"); 
});
```

Comment: How does that differ from my answer?

Comment: The OP didn't include it, so you don't know that it's required ;)

Comment: @MaxTorstensson You should try with getjson instead. or add the "json" in the post.

Comment: i change "data" to "imgval". can anyone advise on how I should send value to a php function then?

Comment: @MaxTorstensson just updated the answwer you can try that one.

Answer (score 0):

and use serialize().. if you have lots of fields in your form

**html**

```
<form name="Apply" id="apply" class="apply_up" method="Post">
...
```

**jquery**

```
$(".apply_up").submit(function(e){    
   $.post("controller/ajax.php",$(this).serialize(), function(data) {
   ...

  //OR
    $.post("controller/ajax.php",$("#apply").serialize(), function(data) {
        alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
    }); 
});
```

Comment: I'd probably be tempted to recommend `$(this).serialize()` for the OP's situation.

Answer (score 0):

Proper solution for most forms:

**HTML**

```
<form action="controller/ajax.php" name="Apply" class="apply_up" method="Post">
    <input type="image" src="img/t_up.png" id="ajax" name="t_up" value="1 ">
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$(".apply_up").on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var formAction = this.action,
        formData = $(this).serialize();

    $.post(formAction, formData, function(data) {
       alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Not necessarily. POST requests have a max size, and sending superfluous data could be expensive in the long run.

Comment: Is that a question to my answer or to the comment the OP already deleted?

Comment: It was the OP's comment that he's deleted. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: To your first comment: sure the requests have a max size, which is per default 8MB. You can imagine how many inputs your form would have to have to exceed this limit in a json string...